# How to toggle a class in Blazor on button click?

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've currently got an onclick event that toggles a class like so:

```
....
<button id="@m.TargetCo.ButtonId" onclick="glyphChanger(this.id)" class="btn btn-default iconButton glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></button>
....
function glyphChanger(buttonID) {
    $("#" + buttonID).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need javascript. You can do this the Blazor way.

**DropDownComponent.razor**

```
<h3>Debug: @buttonCss</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default iconButton glyphicon @buttonCss" @onclick="ChangeButtonClass">Test</button>

@code {
    private string buttonCss = "glyphicon-chevron-right";
    private void ChangeButtonClass()
    {
        buttonCss = buttonCss == "glyphicon-chevron-right" ? "glyphicon-chevron-up" : "glyphicon-chevron-right";
    }
}
```

**Somewhere else in the application**

```
<DropDownComponent/>
<DropDownComponent/>
<DropDownComponent/>
<DropDownComponent/>
```

Comment: That changes the css class for all classes whereas I only want to change it for a specific id, passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @Bhav If you put the code into a component (ie `DropDownComponent.razor`) than it will take on it's own lifecycle. Each component will have it's own `private string buttonCss` managed independently.

Comment: @Bhav check my edit for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of just "glyphicon-chevron-right", my class is "btn btn-default iconButton glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" so its not the cleanest but it works!

Comment: No problem. In that case it sounds like you could change just a portion of the button class. `class="btn btn-default iconButton glyphicon @buttonCss"`